# Upload a remote Video on facebook through a Android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to upload a video on facebook profile. But video is not at my android phone. Video is at a server. I have Url of that video. Is it possible ?

I have used Graph api to upload video from my phone to facebook. Its working fine.
I can also post that url on facebook wall . But i want to upload video not only post url as a string . Can anyone Share his experience to solve this task.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over the server code?

Comment: yes . i have. i have uploaded video at server using FTP.

Comment: Have you try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151708/upload-video-to-facebook-in-android/12470730#12470730

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, install the PHP SDK on the server (or another server side SDK if not PHP), pass the auth-token and other data, such as video title, from the app to the server, and upload the video to FB using the access token provided by the app.

Please let me know if you need more details, but it should be straight forward enough.