# post video on facebook wall in android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I just want to post this video to facebook wall from my android application. When the user clicks it on facebook,that video should be played online.How could I do this?

My Code:

```
byte[] data = null;
String dataPath = "My Video URL here";
String dataMsg = "Your video description here.";
Bundle param;
facebook = new Facebook(FB_APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(dataPath);
    data = readBytes(is);
    param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("message", dataMsg);
    param.putByteArray("video", data);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/videos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}


public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // This dynamically extends to take the bytes you read.
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // This is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes.
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // We need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer.
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    // And then we can return your byte array.
    return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ive added my code upto ive done.But its not working without any error.

Comment: yes.No errors.But it doesnt post URL.

Comment: Have got same problem but now i have solve it. See my answer [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151708/upload-video-to-facebook-in-android) Hope it will help you. If any query then let me know.