# Upload video to facebook by facebook sdk but not display

Tags: android, facebook

At the moment,I am creating an app to upload video to facebook..I used facebook sdk as code follow:

```
   AsyncFacebookRunner mfacebook=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
   mfacebook.request("me/videos", parameters, "POST", new fbRequestListen(), null);
```

I uploaded video success..But numbers of video is increase but it not display in video directory in Facebook..Only have a video in video directory :(

Image reference:
[image]

http://nn8.upanh.com/b4.s29.d2/4577cd2da1157eb014d4529407c148b7_45985628.video1.png

Comment: Simply you have to do some changes and it will works. It successfully work for me. See my anwer [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151708/upload-video-to-facebook-in-android) Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear what you mean by 'video in video directory', but i'll take a stab at this:

If you mean that the `/videos` connection of the user, when accessed with a GET request after you make the upload, does not contain thw newly uploaded video, this is expected for two reasons:

1. The video takes a while to process, and isn't available via the API until processing is complete
2. The `/videos` connection only includes videos the user is tagged in, not the videos that the user owns or uploaded.

You should save the callback from the video upload call, which is the video ID - this will be accessible via the API once processing completes.

In the Graph API , you can get a list of the user's uploaded videos at `/me/videos/uploaded`

You can also access the user's list of uploaded videos via FQL:
`SELECT vid, owner, title, description, thumbnail_link, embed_html, updated_time, created_time FROM video WHERE owner=me()`